# Plot timestamps showing milliseconds with Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly, posixct

I'm trying to plot a time series with Plotly which includes milliseconds. However, Plotly rounds each timestamp to the nearest second when displaying the data. I would like the data to be plotted so that the points are evenly spaced along the x-axis so I don't get this "step" pattern you see in the below plot.

```
library(plotly)

# make some data
x <- seq(1, 10000, by=250)/1000
y <- 1:length(x)

# convert to POSIX
x <- as.POSIXct(x, origin='1970-01-01', tz='UTC')
# show milisecond format
format(x[1:5], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")

# make data frame
data <- data.frame(x, y)

# make the plot with plotly
plot_ly(data, x=~x, y=~y, type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')
```

[image: Plotly Example]

I tried changing the x-axis ticks to display milliseconds but this did not work for me.

```
layout(xaxis = list(tickformat="%H:%M:%OS3"))
```

**Edit:**
Mohanasundaram answer is a good workaround but I am looking for a way to achieve this while maintaining the "POSIXct" and "POSIXt" classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I found that adding `options("digits.secs"=6)` to my script, before calling plotly, made plotly aware of the milliseconds present in my POSIXct timestamps.

I formatted the timestamps with:

```
df$Timestamp = as.POSIXct(D_blinks$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

and asked plotly to display the milliseconds using:

```
layout( xaxis = list(tickformat="%H:%M:%S.%L ms") )
```

I hope it helps someone!

Comment: Setting `options("digits.secs"=6)` works. Thanks! Seems to work fine without changing the Plotly xaxis layout.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that they x were not having sufficient significance to be differentiated by milliseconds.

```
library(plotly)

# make some data
x <- seq(1, 10, by=.25)
y <- 1:length(x)

# convert to POSIX
x <- as.POSIXct(x, origin='1970-01-01')
# show milisecond format

x <- format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3")
# make data frame
data <- data.frame(x, y)

# make the plot with plotly
plot_ly(data, x=~x, y=~y, type='scatter', mode='lines+markers')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your input Mohanasundaram. However, the values themselves are still rounded. I'm trying to remove the "step" pattern you see in the plot. In this plot, I would want to see a straight linear line. Does that make sense? I have updated the question to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks again @Mohanasundaram. This is a good workaround but still not exactly what I am after because this is just converting `x` to a character class and consequently we lose out on using Plotly's dynamic formatting of datetimes (i.e. shows date once followed by timestamps). I have updated the question again.